# How to query all the databases in Raven db using Raven studio

Tags: nosql, ravendb, ravendb-studio, ravenhq

I have this query which I want to execute on all the databases present in my Raven server

```
from result in results 
where result.deleted == false
select new { result.Name }
```

Currently I can execute this query on single database at a time. So is there any way that I can execute it on all the DBs in one go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to execute it on all databases, you would have to execute it on each in turn